# How can I dissmiss this AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'have to add product in a cart using a seekbar with the amount in a alertdialog. My problem is to hide this alertdialog and come back to my orginal view.

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem please ?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    ProductDetail.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = ProductDetail.this
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_dialog, null);
            builder.setView(v1).setIcon(R.drawable.basket)
                    .setTitle("Add " + Product_name + " to your list");

            SeekBar sbBetVal = (SeekBar) v1.findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);

            tvBetVal = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.total_price);
            Button b1 =(Button)v1.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button b2=(Button)v1.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {


                }
            });
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("Prixtotal",""+v22);
                    new CreateNewProduct().execute();

                }
            });
```

Comment: try this way `AlertDialog OptionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();` then just `OptionDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: Did you tried "builder.cancel()" or "builder.dismiss()"?

Comment: Perhaps you need to declare `final AlertDialog.Builder builder...`

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no any `stop()` and `dismiss()` method for [`AlertDialog.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) Class.

You have to create `AlertDialog` Object using `.create()` method of `AlertDialog.Builder` Class.

Then call `.Stop()` or `.dismiss()` on `AlertDialog` Object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
```

then

use

```
alertDialog.show();
```

to show dialog and to dismiss alert use

```
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Perhaps then you need declare AlertDialog as `final`

Answer (score -1):

> My problem is to hide this alertdialog and come back to my original
>   view .

=> You just need to dismiss the dialog. It will automatically come back to your original view, which might be your product list.

You have to create an object of AlertDialog, using which you can call dismiss() method whenever and wherever you would want to dismiss dialog.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
dialog .dismiss();
```

Comment: Down voters, thank you so much. Please care to leave a comment with the reason for down voting.

Comment: -1 Not by me. But Sir how can you call `dialog.dismiss();` inside the `onClick()` method. Please check the code in question again.

Comment: @Kedarnath Has he/she mentioned from where he would want to dismiss dialog exactly? That's why I wrote in my answer "call dismiss() whenever and wherever you would want to dismiss dialog"!

Comment: I think this is new account of him. The same question was posted and downvoted. User got question ban and created new account and ask the same question again.

Comment: But I am not agree with your statement `whenever and wherever`

Comment: If you aren't agree then leave reason(s)! Regarding duplicate question, has to check.

Comment: `wherever` , You cant as AlertDialog is declare inside a block not at class level. `whenever` again wrong since it is not declare as `final`

Comment: @Kedarnath where I have mentioned about declaring/creating object, whether at class level or inside that onClick or somewhere else, have I? My answer is based on some assumptions so pay attention while reading :)

Comment: Sir your answer should be relevant what is asked in the question. :)